# Change the label text only when button command is executing

Tags: python, tkinter

I am preparing a automatic meshing GUI. When I press meshing button, it takes some time to mesh. So, for this duration I want to show a Label saying "Meshing is in progress..." and when meshing is completed, this label text should disappear. 
I am using tkinter's `tk.StringVar()` variable to update the text dynamically.
But I am NOT able to see the first updated text, i.e. "Automatic meshing has started..." text. I could only see second text i.e.`''` (empty string).

I am providing the snippet of that code here:

```
import tkinter as tk

def autoMesh():
    txt.set('Automatic meshing has started...')
    '''
    Meshing related commands here which generally takes 10-15min.
    '''
    txt.set('')
    return

root = tk.Tk()

btn = tk.Button(root, text='Auto-Mesh', command=autoMesh,relief='groove',
                bg='#DDDDDD',fg='blue',width=10,height=2,)
btn.pack(pady=5)

txt = tk.StringVar()
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=txt)
label.pack()
txt.set('Something')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The command is rapidly getting executed.

Comment: No. Actually the `autoMesh` command takes 10-15 mins to executes.

Comment: Can you share the ```Mesh Commands```

Comment: Sorry, But I can't. However, I am pretty sure that those command cannot cause any error, because those commands are Altair SIMLAB based. and this is tkinter related issue.

Comment: the thing is that it will set the text to what You set however it won't get updated until the whole function has finished, so You could use `root.update()` right after `txt.set()` (only the first one)

Comment: If `autoMesh` takes 10-15 mins to execute, better put it in a thread instead.